# Is it possible to auto-generate a polygon on city on android app?

Tags: android, maps, google-maps-android-api-2

Hi guys I wanna ask you if is it possible to auto-draw a geographic boundary as maps.google.com do when you search a city like [this](http://i277.photobucket.com/albums/kk71/ErikaSparrow/cartina.png) with the red dotted line in a maps placed in a fragment on an android app ? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think so its possible, without having latitude and longitude values. Can be made possible by getting some boundaries dynamically.